# Cannot Allocate e.g. 3GB Large Pages

Tags: c++, windows

When I use VirtualAlloc to commit memory I can allocate 3, 4 GB of memory without issues. But when I try to allocate the memory as large pages then I get into trouble.

I get as LastError

> 87   Invalid parameter
>
> or
>
> 1450 Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

On my 32 GB Win 10 Creators Update machine I still have 21,4 GB memory available. The commit count is 17,1 GB so this is also not something to worry about. What is limiting my ability to allocate larger amounts of large pages?

What are large pages useful for if I cannot allocate large amounts of them?

```
#include <windows.h>

int * LargePageAlloc(int64_t numberOfBytesToAllocate)
{
    wprintf(L"\nLarge Page allocator used.");

    HANDLE proc_h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    HANDLE hToken;
    OpenProcessToken(proc_h, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    CloseHandle(proc_h);

    LUID luid;
    ::LookupPrivilegeValue(0, SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME, &luid);

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    auto status = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);
    CloseHandle(hToken);

    if (status != TRUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"\nSeLockMemoryPrivilege could not be acquired. LastError: %d. Use secpol.msc to assign to your user account the SeLockMemoryPrivilege privilege.", ::GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    auto p = (int *)VirtualAlloc(nullptr, numberOfBytesToAllocate, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE | MEM_LARGE_PAGES , PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (::GetLastError() == 1314)
    {
        wprintf(L"\nNo Privilege held. Use secpol.msc to assign to your user account the SeLockMemoryPrivilege privilege.");
    }

    return p;
}


void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *pBuffer = LargePageAlloc(3000uL*1024*1024);
}
```

Comment: Is it C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: I think the only C++ part is nullptr of the sample.

Comment: FYI `::` is C++

Comment: Notice that **`3000*1024*1024`** will lead to **integer overflow**. Did you try `3000U*1024*1024` yet? Though I guess, when you pass this as an *unsigned int*...

Comment: What are you going to *do* with all of it?

Comment: 1. Adjusting the process token privileges *every single call* seems strange.  Surely you only need to do it once.  2.  More to the point, you probably need to do some error checking.

Comment: @Martin:This is only there to make it easier for you to repro it

Comment: @Antti: No. The method is declared as unsigned int. That is fine.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : It *is* integer overflow, but very unlikely to cause problems.

Comment: @RustyX: GetlargePageMinimum returns 2097152.

Comment: @AloisKraus undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Blacksilver: I was hoping to allocate larger pages to get cheaper soft page faults. That turned out to be wrong since now all the cost happens upfront inside VirtualAlloc. Soft faulting in my memory from multiple threads is of no use either because the kernel (at least Win10) seems to have a process global lock for it.

Comment: You must actually *have* the RAM to hold large pages, as those can't be swapped out. "*The memory is always read/write and nonpageable (always resident in physical memory)*". *And* it must be *contiguous* free RAM. Try rebooting and immediately running your application. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: @MartinBonner there was one case of `3000 * 1024 * 1024` being cast to `size_t`, it sure got messy.

Comment: @AnttiHaapal: I have done the types right now. Since that is all passed around in 64 bit registers there is little source for errors except that the compiler is picky about its types.

Comment: These allocations must find contiguous free memory (I think). Did you try right after a reboot?

Comment: @Mat: The machine is running since 1d. Anyway there is little point in using Large Pages if I cannot predict when they will work. And I will not reboot the server every few hours just to be able to use large pages.

Comment: The only apps that take advantage of large pages that I know are things like database servers (and app servers, caches, that sort of think) that are up continuously on servers that do pretty much only that. On a mixed-workload  machine for processes that come and go, fragmentation is going to be an issue.